# How can i replace particular characters in a file

Tags: tcl, tclsh

How to replace  `{` and `}` braces with an alphabet (for example 'a')in a file (.txt) using tcl?

For example the content in file is as below:

```
//-----------------------
main()
{
if (1)
  {
     printf("ok");
  }
else
  {
     printf("not ok");
  }
}
//------------------------------
```

Comment: Put your attempt in the question as well please.

Comment: Do you know how to read a file in and write it out again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    set fp [open work.txt]
    set content [read $fp]
    regsub -all \{ $content "" content
    regsub -all \} $content "" content
    puts $content
```

Answer (score 0):

To transform a *string* with simple replacements, `string map` is the right tool. You just need to write the map a little carefully because you're using unbalanced braces.

```
set transformed [string map { \{ "abc" \} "def" } $original]
```

Demonstrating:

```
% set original "QBC{DEF}SHP"
QBC{DEF}SHP
% set transformed [string map { \{ "abc" \} "def" } $original]
QBCabcDEFdefSHP
```

To transform a file, read the file into a string, do the transform on that string, then write it out again. There are many answers here on Stack Overflow already on how to read and write files.